# Deploying a multi-module Tomcat app with multiple versions of a dependency

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a webapp I'm deploying in Tomcat, with two modules with their own dependencies. I'm running into an issue where a dependency of one of the libraries in module A is a much older version than what is required by a different library in module B.  For example, here are the dependencies in the pom file:

Module A:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.example.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraryA</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Module B:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.another.com</groupId>
        <artifactId>libraryB</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

libraryA then depends on libraryC version 1.0, while libraryB depends on libraryC version 2.0. libraryA will not work with the new version of libraryC, and libraryB will not work with the older version of libraryC. What options do I have (if any) of having these modules live within the same Tomcat webapp, using different versions of these dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the jar hell. first, two potential quick wins:

- maybe you can select some intermediate version of libraryC
- maybe you can migrate libraryA and libraryB to newest version of libraryC. if it's open source just do a pull request

if it's not an option then you will have much more work. rule of the thumb: you can't have different versions of the same class. there is no silver bullet but there are some workarounds.

- splitting application. microservices architecture often helps here but a lot of infrastructure around is needed (monitoring, deployment, configuration etc)
- OSGI. i've never used it so i don't know if and how can you integrate it with tomcat but osgi is a platform for better dependency management (including versioning)
- repackaging. there are tools to take existing source (not sure what about compiled classes) of library x.y.z and create mirror library a.b.c. after that moment they have different names so they can coexists easily. it won't work for every library as some of them refer to themselves using reflection
- different classloaders. you may try to load almost everything in your application with one classloader, libC v1 with second one and libC v2 with third one. but it may require some customization, maybe even custom classloaders. also later you may encounter compatibility problems as class A from classloader 1 is not instance of class A from classloader 2.